# Do I need to sanitize a form if only printing?

Tags: php, html

I have a simple HTML form in a single PHP page. No db, 3 links, no submits to other pages. In place of 'submit' button I'm using a "Print Form" button:

```
<input class="printBtn" type="button" id="printBtn" value="Print Form">
```

with a jQuery listener that invokes 'window.print()' when triggered:

```
    $(document).on('click', '#printBtn', function () {
       window.print();
});
```

This works fine and avoids browser refresh issues by not POSTing on submit. But it also avoids the data sanitizing that would usually be done on a POST submit. Can I ignore the sanitizing if my **only** objective is to print a hardcopy of the completed form?

Comment: what does the form do? what's the action of the form? I see `print the completed form` but what does that fully entail?

Comment: your `code` plz

Comment: The purpose of sanitization is to prevent malicious code from being executed on the *server*. If nothing is sent to the server, if the form is never submitted, then you have little to worry about. Your target audience is also critical: if you are wide-open to the world, then black hats will find your web site. If it is for internal purposes with a known user base, then your risk drops exponentially. If you tell us more about these factors, perhaps we can help further.

Comment: [link](https://scratchpad.online/OHpartYr/OHpartYr.php)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes you can ignore it. It's like a static html form without an action set. A regular submit would trigger nothing (but registered js events).

If the php script which creates the form, accept inputs (e.g. $_GET) You should properly escape them, to avoid cross-site-scripting (XSS)

Answer (score 0):

You can ignore data sanitization. But with the way you wrote, I think the code will even display the input field as well. I'll suggest you submit the form to a PHP file, and display the data with the PHP (even without submitting to database). This will prevent input fields from displaying.